# How to upload blob to MSSQL in Android?

Tags: android, sql-server, blob, jtds

I'm trying to upload a jpg file into MSSQL server using JTDS 1.30 from Android Studio.  I'm able to get my jpg into a blob format (or base64 if needed) using this code:

```
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/storage/sdcard0/Shipright/Pod/test.jpg");
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] blob = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(blob, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

However, the code to actually upload it into the database keeps giving me an error:

```
        try {
            Blob blobUpload = con.createBlob();
            blobUpload.setBytes(0, blob);
            String query = "insert into pics values ('today', 'test.jpg', '11111', 'Jay', '111', '287', '13', ?)";
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
            Timber.d(query);
            ps.setBlob(1, blobUpload);
            ps.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Timber.e("error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
```

I am getting an AbstractMethodError on the con.createBlob line:

> 09-11 10:26:46.246 8462-8462/com.procatdt.sandfile E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                        Process: com.procatdt.sandfile, PID: 8462
>                                                                        java.lang.AbstractMethodError
>                                                                            at
>   net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.createBlob(JtdsConnection.java:2755)
>                                                                            at com.procatdt.sandfile.CopyActivity.onCreate(CopyActivity.java:46)

It doesn't appear that I can upload it to the column directly as a base64 either, as sql server says that I need to convert it to a varbinary(max) first.

Comment: Does it need to be stored in the database or can you save it to a file and save the filename in the DB?

Comment: I have the option to do either.  I'm in control of the table on the SQL server.  I am saving the filename as part of the query, however I need to get the actual file over to the server somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I didn't need to use the createblob() function to initialize the blob.  I just needed to use the setBytes method of PreparedStatement, which converts a byte[] object directly to the necessary blob object.  Here is the working code:

```
    try {
        String query = "insert into podfiles values ('09/28/2017','c:\\temp\\','" + inputFile + "', ?)";
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
        Timber.d(query);
        ps.setBytes(1, blob);
        ps.executeUpdate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Timber.e("Blob Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```